# SonarCloud API endpoint for getting the total numbers of Unit Tests

Tags: metrics, webapi, measure, sonarcloud

Do you know what's the API endpoint needed for me to get the **total number of Unit Tests** in my SonarCloud? The yellow one is the one that I need to get using an API Endpoint upon digging the documentation it is somewhere in the **api/metrics or api/measure** but I have no luck. If you can help me or suggest what API I can use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Already found an answer to this one

```
https://sonarcloud.io/api/measures/component?component={componentKey}&metricKeys=tests
```